# Resolving Layout and Scrolling Issues in a React Video Feed Application with a dynamic Sidebar and dynamic category pill area

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a feed div in my app.js component. This feed div contains another component 'VideoItem' that uses the map function to display a series of videos. I want to be able to scroll down the list of videos in this div without have to scroll down the whole page itself. But everytime I bring out my full sidebar the items in the div go down the page and I have to scroll and it overall breaks the layout of the page since the view height of the sidebar no longer looks like it goes to the bottom and the feed area is the longer. If i use position fixed on the 'bottom-half' of the page I can still scroll through all the contents of my 'sidebar-full' and the scroll through all the categories of my content pills, but the feed area wont scroll to show the rest of my content even if i apply overflow-y: auto or scroll to it.[image: you-1][image: you-2][image: you-3]

my app.js:

```
import './App.scss';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header';
import CategoryBar from './Components/CategoryBar/CategoryBar';
import { videos } from './data';
import VideoItem from './Components/VideoItem/VideoItem';
import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [fullBar, setFullBar] = useState(false);
  const [isToggled, setIsToggled] = useState(false);
 
  const toggleFullbar  = () => {
    setFullBar(!fullBar);
  };
 
  const onToggle = () => {
    setIsToggled(!isToggled);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isToggled) {
      document.body.classList.add('dark-mode');
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    }

    return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    };
  }, [isToggled]);

  return (
    <div className={`App ${isToggled ? 'dark-mode': ''}`}>
      <Header isToggled={isToggled} toggler={toggleFullbar} />
      <div className='bottom-half'>
        <Sidebar className={fullBar ? 'visible' : ''} isToggled={isToggled} onToggle={onToggle}/>
        <div className='right-side'> 
          <div className='categories'>
            <CategoryBar isToggled={isToggled}/>
          </div>
            <div className='feed'>
              {videos.map(video => ( <VideoItem key={video.id} {...video} isToggled={isToggled}/>))}
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my app.scss:

```
.App {
  .bottom-half {
    position: fixed;
    top: 60px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 6px;
    .right-side {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
      .categories{
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
      .feed{
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: grid;
        gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
        margin-right: 34px;
        margin-left: 12px;
      }
    }
  }
}

body.dark-mode {
  background-color: black; /* or your preferred dark background */
  color: #fff; /* or your preferred text color for dark mode */
  /* any other global dark mode styles */
}
```

my videoItem.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { formatDuration } from '../../formatDuration';
import { formatTimeAgo } from "../../formatTimeAgo";
import './VideoItem.scss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import '../../data'

const VIEW_FORMATTER = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, { notation: "compact" })

export function VideoItem({ id, title, channel, views, postedAt, duration, thumbnailUrl, videoUrl, isToggled }) {
  const [isVideoPlaying, setIsVideoPlaying] = useState(false);
  const videoRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    if (!video) return;
  
    const playPromise = video.play();
  
    if (playPromise !== undefined) {
      playPromise.then(() => {
        if (!isVideoPlaying) video.pause();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error attempting to play video:', error);
      });
    }
  
    return () => {
      if (video) video.pause();
    };
  }, [isVideoPlaying]);
  

  return (
    <div className={`video-container ${isToggled ? 'dark-mode': ''}`} onMouseEnter={() => setIsVideoPlaying(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsVideoPlaying(false)}>
        <a className="thumbnail" href={`/watch?v=${id}`}>
            <img className="thumbnail-image" src={thumbnailUrl}/>
            <div className="duration">
                {formatDuration(duration)}
            </div>
            <video className="thumbnail-vid" ref={videoRef} muted playsInline src={videoUrl}/>
        </a>
        <div className="vid-info">
            <a href={`/@${channel.id}`} className="channel-tag">
                <img className="channel-icon" src={channel.profileUrl}/>
            </a>
            <div className="vid-text">
                <a href={`/watch?v${id}`} className="vid-title">
                    {title}
                </a>
                <a href={`/@${channel.id}`} className="channel-name">
                    {channel.name}
                </a>
                <div className="vid-views-and-data">
                {VIEW_FORMATTER.format(views)} Views &#183; {formatTimeAgo(postedAt)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}


VideoItem.propTypes = {
    id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    channel: PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      profileUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    views: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    postedAt: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
    duration: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    thumbnailUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    videoUrl: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default VideoItem
```

videoItem.scss:

```
.video-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0.3rem;
    &:hover .thumbnail-image {
      border-radius: 0; 
    }
  
    &:hover .thumbnail-vid {
      opacity: 1;
      transition-delay: 0.2s;
    }
    &.dark-mode {
      .vid-info {
        .vid-text{
          .vid-title {
            color: white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  .thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  
    .thumbnail-image, .thumbnail-vid {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      border-radius: 0.75rem; 
    }
  
    .duration {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0.25rem;
      right: 0.25rem;
      background-color: #1a1a1a;
      color: white;
      font-size: 0.875rem;
      padding: 0.125rem;
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
    }
  
    .thumbnail-vid {
      opacity: 0; 
      transition: opacity 0.2s, border-radius 0.2s;
    }
    &:hover .thumbnail-vid {
      opacity: 1;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  }
  
  .vid-info {
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.5rem;
  
    .channel-tag {
      flex-shrink: 0;
      img {
        width: 3rem; // 48px, for example
        height: 3rem;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }
    }
  
    .vid-text {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      .vid-title, .channel-name {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
      }
  
      .vid-title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
  
      .channel-name {
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        color: #666; // Example secondary text color
      }
  
      .vid-views-and-data {
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        color: #666;
      }
    }
  }
```

my data.js:

```
export const videos = [
    {
      id: "1",
      title: "CSS Anchor Is The Best New CSS Feature Since Flexbox",
      channel: {
        name: "Web Dev Simplified",
        id: "WebDevSimplified",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKZWeMCsx4Q9e_Hm6nhOOUQ3fv96QGUXiMr1-pPP=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 222536,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-08-29"),
      duration: 938,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/B4Y9Ed4lLAI/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      title: "NEW Way To Create Variables In JavaScript",
      channel: {
        name: "Web Dev Simplified",
        id: "WebDevSimplified",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKZWeMCsx4Q9e_Hm6nhOOUQ3fv96QGUXiMr1-pPP=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 257136,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-08-22"),
      duration: 732,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/d6a8RymS1zI/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      title: "Front-end developer takes on a CSS battle",
      channel: {
        name: "Kevin Powell",
        id: "KevinPowell",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKa6XiLa13mMVPzkmmTBcgNPjjqCGPrY86KfJFmf5w=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 1232300,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-10-05"),
      duration: 120,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eYPyIq5Y3Rk/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      title: "Quick guide to CSS focus states",
      channel: {
        name: "Kevin Powell",
        id: "KevinPowell",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKa6XiLa13mMVPzkmmTBcgNPjjqCGPrY86KfJFmf5w=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 112,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-9-19"),
      duration: 4343,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/apdD69J4bEc/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "5",
      title: "I Cannot Believe React Made A Hook For This",
      channel: {
        name: "Web Dev Simplified",
        id: "WebDevSimplified",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/APkrFKZWeMCsx4Q9e_Hm6nhOOUQ3fv96QGUXiMr1-pPP=s48-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 42345,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-03-02"),
      duration: 1000,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M3mGY0pgFk0/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "6",
      title: "I Got Laid Off...",
      channel: {
        name: "Caleb Curry",
        id: "CalebCurry",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/ytc/APkrFKbpSojje_-tkBQecNtFuPdSCrg3ZT0FhaYjln9k0g=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 10340,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-03-03"),
      duration: 54,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/i2JVQdLnkAY/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "7",
      title: "Tails OS in 100 Seconds",
      channel: {
        name: "Fireship",
        id: "Fireship",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/ytc/APkrFKb--NH6RwAGHYsD3KfxX-SAgWgIHrjR5E4Jb5SDSQ=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 10323340,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-08-09"),
      duration: 100,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mVKAyw0xqxw/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
    {
      id: "8",
      title: "Zig in 100 Seconds",
      channel: {
        name: "Fireship",
        id: "Fireship",
        profileUrl:
          "https://yt3.googleusercontent.com/ytc/APkrFKb--NH6RwAGHYsD3KfxX-SAgWgIHrjR5E4Jb5SDSQ=s176-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      },
      views: 20323340,
      postedAt: new Date("2023-09-09"),
      duration: 105,
      thumbnailUrl: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kxT8-C1vmd4/maxresdefault.jpg",
      videoUrl:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerJoyrides.mp4",
    },
  ]
```

If needed I can also upload the sidebar and categoryBar js and scss.